# Are polynomials dense is L2 of the unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, orthonormal

Let $D$ be the unit disk in the complex plane, and let $X$ be the subset of $L^2(D)$ consisting of polynomials in the complex variable $z=x+iy$ with complex coefficients.  My question is, is $X$ dense in $L^2(D)$?

If not, does anyone know of a function in $L^2(D)$ which cannot be written as an $L^2$ limit of polynomials?

Comment: [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem#Stone–Weierstrass_theorem,_complex_version).

Comment: @CountIblis So then do polynomials in $z$ not separate points?  Because[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53044/71829) seems to be saying polynomials are not dense in the continuous functions for the sup norm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  For instance, $g(z)=\overline{z}$ is orthogonal to every polynomial (proof sketch: if $f(z)=z^n$, then $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_D f\overline{g}=\int_D z^{n+1}=0$ by either direct computation in polar coordinates or using the symmetries of $z^{n+1}$).  It follows that $g$ is not in the closure of the polynomials.

Comment: Are all the L2 limits of polynomials holomorphic?

Comment: I believe that's true but don't recall a proof off the top of my head.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question on that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3175501/71829

Answer (score 0):

Yes. $X$ is dense in $L^2$.

Certainly $X$ is dense in the set of all the continuous functions, $C(D)$. $C(D)$ is also dense in $L^2$, so $X$ is dense in $L^2$.

Comment: Why is $X$ dense in $C(D)$?  [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53044/71829) seems to be sa^ying the polynomials are not dense in $C(D)$ with respect to the sup norm.  Why would the $L^2$ case be any different?